# How many tables with columns get Created in following 4 cases (@MapKey,@MapKeyEnumerated,@MapKeyTemporal,@MapKeyJoinColumn)

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate just stuck in map annotation in hibernate

**CASE 1) @MapKey**

When you use a Map you always need to associate at least two entities. Let's say we have
an Owner entity that relates to the Car entity (Car has a FK to Owner). So, the Owner will have a Map of Car(s):The @MapKey will give you the Car's property used to group a Car to its Owner. For instance, if we have a vin (Vehicle Identification Number) property in Car, we could use it as the carMap key:

```
    @Entity
    public class Owner {
        @Id
        private long id;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
        @MapKey(name = "vin")
        private Map<String, Car> carMap;
    }
    
    @Entity
    public class Car {
        @Id
        private long id;
    
        @ManyToOne
        private Owner owner;
    
        private String vin;
    
    }
```

**CASE 2) @MapKeyEnumerated**

The @MapKeyEnumerated will use an Enum from Car, like WheelDrive:

```
    @Entity
    public class Owner {
        @Id
        private long id;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
        @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private Map<WheelDrive, Car> carMap;
    }
    
    @Entity
    public class Car {
        @Id
        private long id;
    
        @ManyToOne
        private Owner owner;
    
        @Column(name = "wheelDrive")
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private WheelDrive wheelDrive;
    
    }
    
    public enum WheelDrive {
        2WD, 
        4WD;             
    }
```

**CASE 3) @MapKeyTemporal**

The @MapKeyTemporal will use a Date/Calendar field for grouping, like createdOn.

```
    @Entity
    public class Owner {
        @Id
        private long id;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
        @MapKeyTemporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Map<Date, Car> carMap;
    }
    
    @Entity
    public class Car {
        @Id
        private long id;
    
        @ManyToOne
        private Owner owner;
    
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name="created_on")
        private Calendar createdOn;         
    }
```

**Case 4) @MapKeyJoinColumn**

The @MapKeyJoinColumn requires a third entity, like Manufacturer so that you have an association from Owner to Car and car has also an association to a Manufacturer, so that you can group all Owner's Cars by Manufacturer:

```
    @Entity
    public class Owner {
        @Id
        private long id;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
        @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="manufacturer_id")
        private Map<Manufacturer, Car> carMap;
    }
    
    @Entity
    public class Car {
        @Id
        private long id;
    
        @ManyToOne
        private Owner owner;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id")
        private Manufacturer manufacturer;          
    }
    
    @Entity
    public class Manufacturer {
        @Id
        private long id;
    
        private String name;
    }
```

Comment: If you just want to know how many tables will be created, you can set `hbm2ddl` property to `update`. Which will auto-generate tables based on your entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping to a `java.util.Map` doesn't have any impact on the table mapping. In all cases, you are mapping a [Many-to-One/One-to-Many associations](https://thorben-janssen.com/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/). In your table model, this gets represented by 2 database tables. The only exception is the 4th case, where you have another entity and table but that's not part of the actual association mapping.
I explain this mapping in great details on my blog in [How to map an association as a java.util.Map](https://thorben-janssen.com/map-association-java-util-map/)

To sum it up:
Case 1-3 get mapped to 2 database tables: Owner and Car.
Case 4 gets mapped to 3 database tables: Owner, Car and Manufacturer.